# th:each - Sets all attributes in the same column?

Tags: html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have an issue: I load "openhours" from my database into a view (Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday).

But it list all 7 "opening hours" in the Monday column.

Here is the code:

(HTML)

```
<div class="table-hover">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <h4 class="page-header">Opening Hours</h4>

            <tr>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="w: ${op}">
                <div th:if="${w.day == 1}">
                    <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${w.day == 2}">
                    <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${w.day == 3}">
                    <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${w.day == 4}">
                    <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${w.day == 5}">
                    <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${w.day == 6}">
                    <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${w.day == 7}">
                <td th:text="${w.openinghours}"/>
                </div>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Screenshot of the view:

[image]

Any help is appreciated - Thank you so much!

Comment: It's **Tuesday** - not "thuesday" ....

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
<tbody>
                    <td th:text="${op[0].openinghours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${op[1].openinghours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${op[2].openinghours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${op[3].openinghours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${op[4].openinghours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${op[5].openinghours}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${op[6].openinghours}"></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td th:each="w: ${op}" th:text="${w.openinghours}" />
    </tr>
</tbody>
```